# Page Transform for view pager is working unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Here is the code I used to achieve depth transformation from left side of the view pager. But the click of left fragment is working even if it is not selected.

```
@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

    if (position < -1) {
        view.setAlpha(0);
    } else if (position <= 0) {
        view.setAlpha(1 + position);
        view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
        view.setTranslationZ(-1);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);
    } else if (position <= 1) {
        view.setAlpha(1);
        view.setScaleX(1);
        view.setScaleY(1);
        view.setTranslationZ(1);
    } else {
        view.setAlpha(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you see me some more code i can't understand your problem with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem resolved by sending false instead of true in the method.

```
viewpager.setPageTransformer(false, new DepthPageTransformer());
```